# Get all the remote notifications on application launch in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to collect all the remote `notifications` (received when the application was not running) from the android notification center on the application launch.

I have tried using the `NotificationManager.getActiveNotifications` method, but this gives the array of `StatusBarNotification`.
There is a method `getNotification()` available on `StatusBarNotification` but this also does not have the remote notification content.

I have tried something like this,

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
StatusBarNotification[] notifications = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
for (int i = 0; i < notifications.length ; i++) {
    Notification notification = notifications[i].getNotification();
    Log.d("Tag","Notification String = " + notification.toString());
}
```

Output:
`Notification String = Notification(channel=fcm_fallback_notification_channel pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0)`

Please help me with your suggestions.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the notification data then please use

```
Bundle bundle = notification.extras
```

here bundle will have all the data received as payload.
So if you want to get title then use `bundle.getString("android.title")`;